# How can I create a horizontal gradient background for my iOS nav bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, rubymotion

I know how to set a navigation bar background color (with barTintColor), but now I am working on an iOS app that calls for a horizontal gradient (not the typical vertical gradient).

How can I create a navigation bar with a horizontal gradient background?

Comment: Posting this as a resource, I hope it is of some use. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632081/horizontal-cagradientlayer-in-ios-7-0

http://nscookbook.com/2013/04/recipe-20-using-cagradient-layer-in-a-custom-view/

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you want to programmatically set the gradient of a given UINavigationBar I have a solution for you.

First setup a `CAGradientLayer` with your desired colors and locations.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = navigationBar.bounds;
gradientLayer.colors = @[ (__bridge id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
                          (__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor ];
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
```

Then grab the UImage for that layer.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size);
[gradientLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Set the `gradientImage` as the backgroundImage for your `UINavigationBar`.

```
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:gradientImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Swift Solution:

```
[![// Setup the gradient
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = navigationBar.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

// Render the gradient to UIImage
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

 Set the UIImage as background property
navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: THANK YOU! Finally got a chance to implement this and it worked! I first tried adding the layer as a sublayer, but it seemed to conflict with the SVProgressHUD library that I'm using. I was getting the error `[SVIndefiniteAnimatedView _barPosition]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. When I tried setting it as a background image as you suggested, it worked!

Comment: I'll have to add that this code will not take into account the status bar. If you want to have your gradient take over the whole status bar as well you can simply do something like this :

`var updatedFrame = navigationBar.bounds
        updatedFrame.size.height += 20
        gradientLayer.frame = updatedFrame`

Answer (score 17):

Updated @JulianM answer for iOS 10 / swift 3.0:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
var updatedFrame = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
updatedFrame.size.height += 20
gradientLayer.frame = updatedFrame
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift

Add this function in global class

```
func setHorizontalGradientColor(view: UIView) {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    var updatedFrame = view.bounds
    updatedFrame.size.height += 20
    gradientLayer.frame = updatedFrame
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

Use in anywhere:

```
setHorizontalGradientColor(view: self.bgView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gardientImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

for ios 7 navigation bar height is 64px