# Customizing the NavigationBar's background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cagradientlayer

I'm having trouble setting a gradient as the background to my UINaviagtionBar. I've created a class that handles the CAGradientLayer which seems to be fine until I set the gradient to the navigation bar's layer. The buttons and the title fade away once i start going through the stacks and even going back to the topContorller ("Settings" View) the title becomes faded as well.

[image: At Launch of the UINaviagtionController]

[image: Going through the stack]

Here is my code I'm running on the "Settings" view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

CAGradientLayer * randomLayer = [Gradient gold];

randomLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20);

[randomLayer setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
[randomLayer setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer insertSublayer:randomLayer atIndex:1]; 
}
```

maybe there's a way to bring the NavigationBarItems to the front of the layer or maybe another approach? I've first came across this one [Gradient Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889600/how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-gradient-background-for-my-ios-nav-bar), which seems not to work for me. I'm pretty sure I'm missing a step or over thinking it, appreciate the help in advance

Comment: It sounds like you may be adding the gradient many times - have you tried making sure its only called once?

Comment: You write that code may be multiple time for particular navigation controller.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I mean I placed it on viewWillAppear at first and the gradient become darker and darker, an ugly yellow, every time I went back to the settings view which lead me to place it in the viewDidLoad @sschale

Comment: Am i writing the code for that NavigationController? Yes, I've ran that code in the UINavigationController too, which seem to have failed. @PramodTapaniya

Comment: @waffles write this code on customnavigationviewcontroller.m file.

Comment: I ran the code on viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear in the customNavController.m and to my surprise nothing happened. the NavigationBar is just white now. should i still be getting the NavigationBar like this  '[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer insertSublayer:randomLayer atIndex:1];' ? @PramodTapaniya