# How to gradient locations work in iOS?

Tags: ios, colors, hex, gradient

I am working on a little project playing with colors in Xcode.  Was wondering what the gradient locations do.

I noticed that gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0] will make it vertical, so i thought that gradientLayer.locations = [0.5, 0.5] would make it horizontal?

[0.5, 0.5] - results in 2 blocks of color stacked on top of each other, no gradient
[0.0, 1.0] - results in gradient i am looking for, 2 vertical colors, with gradient

I know its kind of vague, but was looking for an explanation here. This doesnt make a lot of sense to me.

Thank,

Matt

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAGradientLayer/locations) say:

> The gradient stops are specified as values between 0 and 1. The values must be monotonically increasing.

So `locations` have actually nothing to do with gradient orientation. Regarding the latter refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632081/horizontal-cagradientlayer-in-ios-7-0) question. Locations mean location where gradient *stop*, eg. in first view *red* begins at 0 (top) and ends at 0.5 (middle), so further to bottom can be only *solid blue*. If you give [0.5, 0.5], it means, that both gradients should begin *and* end in the middle, so the colors don't mix at all.

Code producing the below gradients:

```
@interface TestViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view4;

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *views = @[_view1, _view2, _view3, _view4];

    for (UIView *view in views) {
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    }

    // 1
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer new];
    gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
    gradient.frame = _view1.bounds;
    gradient.locations = @[@0.0, @0.5];
    [_view1.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    // 2
    gradient = [CAGradientLayer new];
    gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
    gradient.frame = _view2.bounds;
    gradient.locations = @[@0.5, @1.0];
    [_view2.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    // 3
    gradient = [CAGradientLayer new];
    gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
    gradient.frame = _view2.bounds;
    gradient.locations = @[@0.0, @0.5, @1.0];
    [_view3.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    // 4
    gradient = [CAGradientLayer new];
    gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
    gradient.frame = _view4.bounds;
    gradient.locations = @[@0.0, @0.8, @1.0];
    [_view4.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}

@end
```

[image: gradients]

Comment: Good explanation and nice demo, have enough to try and implement with swift. thanks.

Comment: ah, the little green check mark? that must be it. was kind of confused, but I got it thanks!

Comment: @MattCatellier yes, besides if you check an answer as accepted, you get some reputation too ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is quite an old answer, and coming across it I thought that I'd update the accepted answer for Swift.

```
    for view in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }

    // 1
    var gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradient.frame = view1.bounds
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.5]
    view1.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

    // 2
    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradient.frame = view2.bounds
    gradient.locations = [0.5, 1.0]
    view2.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

    // 3
    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
    gradient.frame = view3.bounds
    gradient.locations = [0, 0.5, 1.0]
    view3.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

    // 4
    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
    gradient.frame = view4.bounds
    gradient.locations = [0, 0.8, 1.0]
    view4.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

I've backed this up with a GitHub link for anyone interested https://github.com/stevencurtis/Gradients